# Bidimensional lists in python

Tags: python, list

why this code:

```
grid = [[" "] * 10] * 5

for c in range(10):
  grid[0][c] = '#'

for r in grid:
  print(r)
```

outputs this?

```
['#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#']
['#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#']
['#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#']
['#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#']
['#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#']
```

I'm fixing the first index to be 0. No other sublist should change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create new values and not reference them again!

```
grid = [[" " for _ in range(10)] for __ in range(5)] 

for c in range(10):
  grid[0][c] = '#'

for r in grid:
  print(r)
```

```
['#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#']
[' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']
[' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']
[' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']
[' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']
```